# When using the Database window is it possible to put a table tab in Window mode in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.2

I am using the `View -> Tools -> Database` feature a lot in PhpStorm 2018.2. I like to put this view in windowed mode and move it to my second monitor. Now when I click on a table it opens up in main PhpStorm window.

Is it possible to open tables also in a separate window? This way I can put them next to each other on the second monitor and keep focus on programming on my main monitor.

Comment: If I understood you correctly .... you may just drag your Table tab from main window and drop in on second monitor -- it should create new Editor there (works with code files for sure). The other tables may still be opened in your main editor .. but you can just manually drag them there as well...

Comment: You're right, that does indeed creates a new window except it does not create the workflow I was hoping for. Basically I want to click on a table (in the database window) and want it to open on the second monitor (in the table tab i just dragged and positioned next to it). Now it opens up a new tab in the editor on the main monitor. It's obviously because there is no relation between database window and the table window. It helps though to be able to put the table on the second monitor by dragging. Thanks